# Unable to create file in workspace Audience validation failed 401

Tags: azure-service-principal, powerbi-rest-api, microsoft-fabric

Creating file in workspace with REST API:

PUT  [https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/{workspace}/{item}.{itemtype}/Files/sample?resource=file](https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Bitem%7D.%7Bitemtype%7D/Files/sample?resource=file)

Status code:401 Unauthorized

Error: Authentication Failed with Audience validation failed for audience 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'

The application has all Power Bi permissions with consent still can't create a file.

Similar problem found here with no solution
[Creating OneLake files through REST API calls fail... - Microsoft Fabric Community](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Creating-OneLake-files-through-REST-API-calls-fails/m-p/3285932)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if you are generating **access token** with Power BI scope and using it to create file in One Lake workspace.

I generated one access token using client credentials flow with **Power Bi** scope like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to create file in One Lake workspace, I too got **same error** as below:

```
PUT https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/FabricWS/Lakehouse01.Lakehouse/Files/sample.txt?resource=file
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token with **Storage** scope and use that token to create file in workspace.

In the registered application, I added Storage `API permission` as below:

[image]

Now, I generated access token with **Storage** scope using client credentials flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to create file in One Lake workspace, I got `201 Created` **response** like below:

```
PUT https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/FabricWS/Lakehouse01.Lakehouse/Files/sample.txt?resource=file
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where file created successfully in workspace like this:

[image]